# Cancan 2.0, how to restrict user to update certain attributes on User model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancan

There's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921591/cancan-limiting-a-users-ability-to-set-certain-model-attributes-based-on-their) already answered but seems to be a little outdated since it doesn't cover the new CanCan 2.0 version. I need to prevent certain fields (in this case `:active` and `:limited`) from being updated by the user and be able to only be edited by an admin.

```
# ability.rb
if user.persisted?
  cannot :update, :users, [:active, :limited]

  elsif user.admin?
    can :access, :all
  end
```

However this code is not preventing a user from editing those fields.

I also added the `enable_authorization` to a new `class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController` and `devise_for :users, path: 'users', controller: 'registrations'` on routes but that doesn't seem to make it either.

Answer (score -1):

I think it should be User not :users?

`# ability.rb
    ...
    cannot :update, User, [:active, :limited]`