# How to restrict a user from updating certain fields with CanCanCan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cancancan

So if I have a User, and he can create/update his Service, but he cannot :publish(bool) them, what would be the best solution to skip this field from the update_params hash?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921591/cancan-limiting-a-users-ability-to-set-certain-model-attributes-based-on-their) similar question, but it links to CanCan 2.0 which never got released, and I was wondering if there is a way to solve this problem using CanCanCan, but could not find anything in their documentation. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't.  I would have a seperate publish action.  So I'd omit publish from the form and the `service_params` entirely.

Then I'd do something like this:

```
Class ServicesController

  def publish
    @service = Service.find(params[:id])  
    @service.update_column(:publish, true)
  end

end
```

Then in ability

```
can :manage, Service
cannot :publish, Service
```

Alternatively you could do this (assuming you have a current user and something defining them as an admin)

```
def service_params
  if current_user.admin?
    params.require(:service).permit(:my_field, :publish)
  else
    params.require(:service).permit(:my_field)
  end
end
```

So you'd be omitting it from the parameters if they're not an admin.  In this case you'd probably want to hide the fields in the view dependent on whether or not they can change the field.

Comment: when performing a simple task like Service update, this will require two forms to exist, or even two different pages. What if I would like to use one form?

Comment: No it wouldn't, you just need an if statement around the fields. e.g. `if current_user.admin?`